# Prove $f_n(x)=\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt{x}$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

From Spivak's Calculus 24-2:

> Prove $f_n(x)=\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt{x}$  converges uniformly on
>   $\mathbb{R}$.

My issue is whether this makes sense since square root of negative numbers are not yet defined.  In the book complex numbers have not been covered.  In any case can anyone offer up a solution?

Comment: That's a good point. If $f_n:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$ then indeed the square root of negative numbers is undefined, so we do not have uniform convergence on all of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I think you should just assume it is defined over the interval $x \geq 0$.

Comment: Hint: $f_n(x)$ is decreasing in $x$ (why?).

Answer (score -1):

Correct me if wrong:

Let

$f_n (x):= \sqrt{x+1/n} -\sqrt{x}$, $x\ge 0.$

$|\sqrt{x+1/n}-\sqrt{x}| =$

$(1/n)|\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x+1/n} +\sqrt{x}}| \le$

$(1/n)\sqrt{n} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}.$

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be given.

Choose $n_0 \gt \dfrac{1}{\epsilon^2}.$

For $n \ge n_0 :$

$|f_n(x)| \lt \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \le \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n_0}} \lt \epsilon,$ I.e.

$f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $0$  on $\mathbb{R_+}.$

Answer (score -2):

If you use
$(1+x/2)^2
=1+x+x^2/4
\gt 1+x
$,
you get
$\sqrt{1+x}
\lt 1+x/2
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt{x+1/n}-\sqrt{x}
&=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+1/(nx)}-\sqrt{x}\\
&\lt\sqrt{x}(1+1/(2nx))-\sqrt{x}\\
&\lt\sqrt{x}(1+1/(2nx))-\sqrt{x}\\
&=\sqrt{x}+1/(2n\sqrt{x})-\sqrt{x}\\
&\dfrac1{2n\sqrt{x}}\\
\end{array}
$

and this should gove you what you need.